# How not to reload CollectionView after clicking on Back button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi I'm facing a problem with my small xamarin app.

I have my small xamarin-form app that everytime the user enter a product Id click OK button retrieves a single (data related to that product Id only) data thru Web API from page A, and then pass it to a collectionview in another page B.

then there is a back button to go back to page A and the user must enter another product Id again and the app must fetch data thru web api again and pass it again to page B in the collectionview.

So the problem is now, when I click on back button in Page B, it's clear the collectionview data, whereas I need the collectionview to keep the state even If I pop back.

I'm not using any MVVM pattern or complicated stuff from now as I'm new to xamarin; it's just a simple architecture.

Or maybe I'm using wrong technics to achieve this and can advise me a better way to achieve that. I'm please open to your suggestion !!!

**In brief, I need to be able not to reload CollectionView after clicking on Back button.**

**Below is the code that Bind to the View on Page B**

```
public async void OnGetProductDetailButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProductDetailPage
    {
        BindingContext = productDetails
    });

}
```

Comment: Well, the data in collection view will always be reload on page reappearing if that is how you have it set up. Personally I would recommend you set up some sort of local DB (SQLite, Realm) and load data from there. Otherwise if you want it super simple just pass the data of the collection view to your new page, and then when you go back send the data back.

Comment: every time you call `new ProductDetailPage` it creates a **new** page.  If you want to reuse the same page, store a reference to it and reuse it instead of creating a new one

Comment: @Jason Please how do i do it? Programmatically

Comment: Each time when you navigate from A to B. Will it be data different? About storing reference. Keep ProductDetailPage variable in the class level then use the same and only change BindingContext  `ProductDetailPage productPageObj = new ProductDetailPage { BindingContext = productDetails }; await Navigation.PushAsync(productPageObj);`

Comment: @CodingValue You want to store old data and save new data in collectionview in Page B when navigate to Page B again?

Comment: You need to keep the data "somewhere" in a list, and then use that list as ItemsSource of the CollectionView. For a simple app, just keep the list in a **static variable**. `class ProductDetailPage() { public static ObservableCollection<MyProductClass> Products { get; } = new ObservableCollection<MyProductClass>(); }`. Then before each call to Page B, do `ProductDetailPage.Products.Add(new MyProductClass(..params..);` Show more code, to get a more complete answer of what to change.